# How to groupby then toList the toMap using java8 stream

Tags: java, group-by, java-8, java-stream

The original data is like:

```
[
    { 'k1': 'gbv1', 'k2': 'v2' },
    { 'k1': 'gbv1', 'k2': 'v4' },
]
```

The required data is like:

```
{
    'gbv1': { 'v2': true, 'v4': true },
}
```

i.e. Group by `k1` and then Select value of `k2`.

What I currently have:

```
examples.stream().collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(Example::getK1,
        Collectors.mapping(Example::getK2,
                Collectors.toList())));
```

It returns a list of value of `k2` not a map;

I'm most of the time with javascript and it's easy to do such kind of work because it's dynamic I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `toMap` instead of `mapping`:

```
Map<String,Map<String,Boolean>> map =
    examples.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Example::getK1,
                     Collectors.toMap(Example::getK2,v->true,(v1,v2)->v1)));
```

This is assuming both `getK1()` and `getK2()` return a `String`.

Comment: It throws `Duplicate key true`